# c++ - targeting OpenGL 2.0

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm querying the function pointers by hand and wondering if I'm targeting OpenGL 2.0 as a minimum requirement, when should I use the extension-variant of the functions?

Let me ask you with an example. Here is the gl.spec file:
https://www.opengl.org/registry/oldspecs//gl.spec

I suppose that the <= 2.0 functions are also available when targeting 2.0, so let's check the "OpenGL 1.2 command" section. There is a function called TexImage3D which is available when the EXT_texture3D is supported.

Another example would be the ("OpenGL 2.0 command" section) DrawBuffers function. Is it only available if ARB_draw_buffers is implemented?

The extensions should be used when targeting <= 2.0, shouldn't they? If a driver is implementing OpenGL 2.0, do I have to use extensions at all?

Comment: The *.spec files were superseded by the XML format. Don't use them anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just skipped the first lines of the file where you can find the warning. Anyway, here is the corresponding xml file: https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/gl.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting a specific version of OpenGL, then you should *never* use the extension equivalent.

For example:

> There is a function called TexImage3D which is available when the EXT_texture3D is supported.

No, it is not. `glTexImage3D` is available in OpenGL 1.2. `glTexImage3DEXT` is provided by EXT_texture_3d. They are not the same function, and there is no guarantee that calling `glTexImage3DEXT` will be exactly equivalent to calling `glTexImage3D`.

> If a driver is implementing OpenGL 2.0, do I have to use extensions at all?

Not unless you want to use an extension for functionality not provided by OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: Thanks! Right now I'm getting the listed functions (on Windows) with

    wglGetProcAddress

and a group of some 3.0 core functions which are provided by the extension ARB_framebuffer_object. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: One more: so the functions listed <= 2.0 (so not the ARB extensions) will work on most of the GPUs? OGL 2.0 is already old and if a card cannot handle 2.0 commands, it wouldn't be able to render the game anyway. Is this correct?